What is the correct term for an Inversion of an Inversion? Relating to computer science and Two's Complement in binary.
Relating to Computer Science, what term do I describe Two's Completement of Two's Complement as?
Two's Complement inverts the digits and adds 1.
In binary:
0100 0010 = 66
Two's Complement of 0100 0010 = 1011 1110 = -66
Two's Complement of 1011 1110 = 0100 0010 = 66
I'm not sure if commutative is the correct term. It could be more closely related to the inversion of an inversion rather than ordering.

In math, an operation that is its own inverse is called an "involution". Notice that this is equivalent to "doing it twice in a row gets you back to where you started". And any time I see the term "inversion" used, I have a very high expectation that the operation in question is an involution.

@JonathanZ I'd like to post this as the answer.

Sure, go ahead. Feel free to make any additions or edits to it that you think would improve it, and thanks for asking beforehand!

I'll ask if there is a computer term for it.

$10000010$ is the representation of $-126$, not $-66$, in two's complement binary arithmetic. The two's complement of $01000010$ is $10111110$, which represents $-66$. But when you take the two's complement of $10111110$ you get $01000010$ again, so the "two's complement" function is indeed an involution.

@David K I took my values from https://www.allmath.com/twos-complement.php today which gave these values:
66 0100 0010
-66 1011 1110
So, my apologies for that - I must have been looking at a different source when I posted, or simply typed in the wrong numbers for 66.
I've amended my question now.

In mathematics, an involution, involutory function, or self-inverse function is a function f that is its own inverse,
f(f(x)) = x
for all x in the domain of f.
Equivalently, applying f twice produces the original value.
